# How to display hyperlink in Access form (Datasheet View)

Tags: ms-access

One field of the table is a memo field that contains the full path of a file.

I am to display the path as a hyperlink in a form in datasheet view.

This is what I have done in the Property window for that column:

- Is Hyperlink: Yes
- Display as Hyperlink: Always

Now the value of that column does display like a hyperlink, in blue color and with a underline. But if I click the hyperlink, it does not take me to anywhere.

There is a property named "Hyperlink Target", which I think must be the place to fix that. But nowhere can I find documentation for the value for this property. I tried "_blank" as if it were Html, but it fails. Can anyone tell me what is supposed to be in that property so that the hyperlink will work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your form's record source query, concatenate a hash character (`#`) to both ends of the memo field value.

```sql
SELECT '#' & your_field & '#' AS URL
FROM YourTable;
```

Then if your field contained `https://www.google.com/webhp?source=search_app`, the text box value would be `#https://www.google.com/webhp?source=search_app#`.  And clicking the text box bound to that URL would use the `FollowHyperlink` method to open it in the associated application.

If you're talking about a local file path rather than a web URL, that method will still work.

Comment: +1 for the hashes! Typical Micro$oft; the one simple and stupid thing you haven't tried yet out of 100 possible things :-)

Answer (score 4):

Are you really attached to this idea? I would not recommend it because it makes editing the data a nuisance. I prefer FollowHyperlink in the double-click event. FollowHyperlink will open most things:

```
 FollowHyperlink "c:\docs\word.doc"
 FollowHyperlink "mailto:sample@example.com"
 FollowHyperlink "http://stackoverflow.com
 FollowHyperlink Me.MyDocs
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to figure this out with additionally adding a field into it. The solution I found was to write a SQL Update Query:

```
UPDATE TableName
SET Yahoo = [FieldName]&'.Y'&"#"&"http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s="& [FieldName] & "&ql=0"&"#"
WHERE [FieldName]IS NOT NULL
```

My specific use was for linking to Stock Tickers, but it could be used for other purposes. The issue that this solved for me was Access erroring out thinking the "#" was for a date.